# How to print a stateflow chart as svg file

Tags: matlab, svg, stateflow

I would like to print an existing stateflow chart to a svg file.  I have found...

```
sfprint
```

...but sfprint does not support svg format.  BUT, when I use "Export to web..." from my simulink model the generated webview has the stateflow diagrams as an SVG, so it seems this must be possible.

I am using matlab version R2010a.

Comment: With respect to sharing and viewing Simulink models, this blog post may be also of interest: http://blogs.itemis.com/embedded/view-simulink-and-stateflow-models-without-simulink

Answer (score 1):

Matlab Syntax : slwebview

Export Simulink models to Web views

```
slwebview
filename = slwebview(system_name)
filename = slwebview(system_name,Name,Value)
```

A Web view is an interactive rendition of a model that you can view in a Web browser. You can navigate a Web view hierarchically to examine specific subsystems and to see properties of blocks and signals.

You can use Web views to share models with people who do not have Simulink installed.

Web views require a Web browser that supports Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG).

Reference Link : http://de.mathworks.com/help/rptgenext/ug/slwebview.html

Comment: thx for the respone, but what I would like to do is print only the active stateflow chart to a single SVG file.  as stated in the original post, it is clear that webview uses SVG images for stateflow charts.